# 'Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable' error message

Tags: python, postgresql, geopandas

I have a postgres spatial table that I want to convert to a geopandas GeoDataFrame. In order to do so I wrote the following piece of code:

```
#'pg_tab_clip' is the name of the postgres spatial table
#'b' is an integer
#'con' is the connection to postgres

    select = etl.fromdb(con, "SELECT ST_AsText(geom) FROM {0} WHERE buffer = {1}".format(pg_tab_clip, b))
    temp = select[1:len(select)]
    buffer_polygs = [shapely.wkt.loads(t[0]) for t in temp]

    buffer_gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame()
    for i, bp in enumerate(buffer_polygs):
        buffer_gdf.loc[i, 'geometry'] = bp
```

When I run the script I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "....py", line 417, in <module>
    main(working_folder, alr_path, pg_tab_culv, N, margin, pg_con)
  File "....py", line 390, in main
    loop_tiles(N, margin, con, cursor, alr_path, srid, pg_tab_buf, pg_tab_tile1, pg_tab_clip, buf)
  File "....py", line 274, in loop_tiles
    process_raster(con, pg_tab_clip, tile2_tif, srid, i, j, margin, culv_count, buf)
  File "....py", line 143, in process_raster
    buffer_gdf.loc[i, 'geometry'] = bp
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 190, in __setitem__
    self._setitem_with_indexer(indexer, value)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 366, in _setitem_with_indexer
    self._setitem_with_indexer(new_indexer, value)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 611, in _setitem_with_indexer
    raise ValueError('Must have equal len keys and value '
ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable
```

I don't know what's causing this problem. The strangest of all is that the script doesn't actually fail every time I run it but only sometimes (???).
Also, is there perhaps a more elegant/pythonic way to do what I am trying to do? Is the iterable 'buffer_polygs' actually unnecessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
buffer_gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=buffer_polygs)
```

Another way using [from_postgis](http://geopandas.org/reference.html?highlight=from_postgis#geopandas.GeoDataFrame.from_postgis) copied from the answer to [Geopandas PostGIS connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36732075/geopandas-postgis-connection):

```
import geopandas as gpd
import psycopg2  # (if it is postgres/postgis)

con = psycopg2.connect(database="your database", user="user", password="password",
    host="your host")
sql = "select geom, x,y,z from your_table"
df = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_postgis(sql, con, geom_col='geom' )
```

Comment: First answer seems to be working fine and second answer is a very useful tip. Excellent.

Comment: Any ideas what the error I was getting is about? It's quite strange because I have divided a UK raster in 91 tiles (13x7) and I do some processing on each of them using the code I mentioned before. It works well until it reaches the tile number 67. Then it throws that error.

Comment: Nice. No sorry I dont know what is causing the error

Comment: I got similar error when the geometry I try to assign is a "MultiPolygon", instead of a "Polygon". Maybe only tile 67 is MultiPolygon.

Comment: Yeah, the problem happens when assigning a MultiPolygon to a cell in a dataframe, but I don't know how to fix that yet.